# Order Users with most Songs Desc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, models

Hopefully a simple question. I have several models, two of them, `:users` and `:songs`, interact to get data from the database.

A User `has_many :songs`.

I'm trying to find the users with the most songs in the `USER INDEX` action, i.e list the 10 users with the most songs, user with the most songs at the top, descending.

So far I have in the `users_controller` in `index`;

`@users = User.all`

And so far all I can do in the view, `users/index`;

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= user.name %><%= user.songs.count %>
<% end %>
```

Works, it counts the songs but how do I order by users with most songs?

I have been looking at sort_by inside the block and I guess it could be done by listing all songs and grouping them by the user, but I feel that is not efficient enough. -as you can see I'm not an advanced developer.

Please tell me what you guys think and the answer to my solution if possible. The thing that is confusing me is that I am ordering a list generating from a table by data generated by another table. Must be simple but I haven't done it before so I can't get my head around it.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
User.all(:limit => 10, :order => "(select count(user_id) from songs where user_id = users.id) DESC")
```

Comment: This is of course also valid, but is more like hand-crafted SQL than using the ORM. However it should be even more efficient as less data is transferred from db.

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like this:

```
User.includes(:songs).order{|x| x.songs.size}
```

This does everything in one query so it should be more efficient than for example

```
User.all.sort{|x| user.songs.size}
```

Which would perform a query for each user

Comment: Thanks for the information, in your answer and in your comment in the other answer. Unfortunately, I couldn't get this to work, undoubtedly because I must not have done it properly. But I still want to learn from both examples. Could you give me a bit of extra guidance with this example? Just to learn from it. I put it into the users_controller, (I also tried it in the block as a second attempt, but it looks like it belongs in the controller). And I didn't change anything else. Where would one go from here?

Comment: I'm going to use the other answer for efficiency based on your advice in the comment - so yeah, again, thanks for your advice there :).